# Launch MSTest on TeamCity with MSBuild package

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, mstest, teamcity-9.0

I have a solution build with VS 2013.
On teamcity I used MSBuild to build it.
Is that possible to launch MSTests with MSBuild?
What if I'll install VS2013 community edition? Will it help to launch MSTests?

Answer (score 0):

[Agents for Visual Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=40750) installs all necessary packages.